# React Route Component handle all "/" routes EXCEPT for "/login"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

Dashboard component renders too, while I am entering `/login`. I need to omit Dashboard component while in Login.

**Exact** attribute does not fit because *Dashboard* has nested paths like `/dashboard/users`, `/dashboard/settings`

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Route path='/'>
         <div>
             <Route path='/login'   component={Login}       exact   />
             <Route path='/'        component={Dashboard}           />
         </div>
    </Route>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Try removing `path='/'` from second `<Route/>`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could use `Switch` to render the first matching `Route`

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Route path='/'>
         <div>
            <Switch>
              <Route path='/login'   component={Login}       exact   />
              <Route path='/'        component={Dashboard}           />
            </Switch>
         </div>
    </Route>
</BrowserRouter>
```